# How to use RNN cell in a network?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use a customized RNN cell in my network. I started with the RNN cell example of Keras where the RNN cell is defined as MinimalRNNCell. When I am trying to use the defined cell in my recurrent network, by replacing a simpleRNN that I was using previously with the customized RNN cell, but this error shows up:

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

```
class MinimalRNNCell(Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

# Let's use this cell in a RNN layer:

cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = keras.Input((None, n_f))
layer = RNN(cell)
y = layer(x)


# prepare sequence
length = 10
n_f = 10
# define LSTM configuration
n_neurons = length
n_batch = length
n_epoch = 1000
# create LSTM
model = Sequential()
#model.add(SimpleRNN(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, n_f)   ,return_sequences=True))
model.add(RNN(cell, input_shape=(length, n_f) ,return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_neurons)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())
# train LSTM
ES = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience= int(n_epoch/2))
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data= (X_Val,y_Val),epochs=n_epoch, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=2 , callbacks=[ES])
```

Comment: My only guess is because you are using relu. Maybe you are inputting 0? because a relu has no gradient at 0

Comment: I tried that, it's not because of ReLu. It's probably because of the way I am using it, or the wrong way of giving it inputs.

Comment: What line does it fail on? Maybe try scaling to network down to a length of just 2 or 3 to test